Generate all combinations of a string where individual words are replaced with alternatives
I'd like to create a function to generate all combinations of a full name where all variants of alternative individual names are replaced.
The following gets me part of the way there:
ALT_NAMES = {
    "Anthony": ["Tony", "Ant"],
    "Christopher": ["Chris"],
}

def generate_alt_names(name: str):
    yield name

    names = name.split()
    
    for idx, single_name in enumerate(names):
        alt_names = ALT_NAMES.get(single_name, [])

        for alt_name in alt_names:
            yield " ".join(names[:idx] + [alt_name] + names[idx + 1 :])


def main():
    print(list(generate_alt_names("Anthony Christopher Clark")))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It outputs:
[
    "Anthony Christopher Clark",
    "Tony Christopher Clark",
    "Ant Christopher Clark",
    "Anthony Chris Clark",
]

However, this is missing combinations where multiple individual names have been replaced:
[
    "Tony Chris Clark",
    "Ant Chris Clark",
]

I think the answer lies with one of the itertools functions or recursion of some kind but I'm struggling to come up with a solution. Would anyone be able to set me on the right track?
